# How to properly import an eclipse java project into VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have got an eclipse java project and opening it in IntelliJ worked fine but now I tried to open it in VSCode and there are a bunch of `package does not exist` error even though everything is on the right place. Is there any procedure how one should import existing java projects into VSCode?